# WSO2ESB SOAP 1.2 to SOAP 1.1 proxy, third attempt

Tags: soap, wso2-esb

Does anybody know or have even a hist how to implement SOAP 1.1 to SOAP 1.2 proxy using WSO2ESB?
Any combination of any configuration options lead to:
SOAP 1.2 request get transformed to SOAP 1.1 request, 
but response from SOAP 1.1 service doesn't get transformed to SOAP 1.2.
None on examples, documentation articles fits to my case. Looks like everybody think that it should work our of the box, but it doesn't.

Comment: Which ESB version are you using? There is an unconfirmed issue at https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-1994 on ESB 4.6.0 using PassThru Transport. If you're using 4.6.0 - try your configuration in ESB 4.5.1 or switch to the HTTP-NIO transport in ESB 4.6.0.

Comment: Yes, I have 4.6.0, and this one is my ticket actually. Pity if I have to roll back to 4.5.1. I'll check if I can switch to HTTP NIO. Thank you for a suggestion. Consider this as solved.

Comment: You shouldn't need to switch to 4.5.1 I just recommended that as the lazy alternative of switching the transport in 4.6.0 :)

Comment: Thank you. I received the same suggestion with step-by-step instructions from WSO2 team. Not sure if I can post them here.